# Merging WMS with another layer type using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wms, soilgrids

I loaded in Soil Organic Carbon data into ArcMap from SoilGrids through WMS and then added in a layer of coordinates. The idea here is that I extract the soil carbon data at each coordinate point but I can't seem to use the Merge tool like normal. I think this issue is rooted in the fact that these two layers are not the same ~type~ of data. I am very much a beginner at ArcMap so I am not sure how to proceed.

UPDATE:

It didn't seem to work - loading it in as a WCS the same way still doesn't seem to let me use any sort of geoprocessing tools. It seems like the server keeps disconnecting after I load in the file (there's a red X over the specific server in the Catalog). Maybe this is the root of the issue?

Comment: I don't think you can extract/analyse data on a WMS layer.  You need to get your data as a feature class layer (eg, shapefile, file geodatabase, or similar) before you can perform these sorts of actions on it.

Comment: Soil Grids, I think, do a WCS, which would allow you to get the data, rather than an image representation.

Answer (score 1):

The WMS returns an image representing the map, the values in that image are determined by the colour scale and do not correspond to the actual values of the map. You use WMS only for visualisation, for example to compose a multi-layer map print out, or in a web mapping interface.

To perform that kind of value operation you need to load the WCS instead. In the case of SoilGrids the WCS URL is the same as for WMS, for instance: https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/soc.map . Just point the WCS dialogue in your GIS software to it.

All available SoilGrids services are listed in [this page](http://maps.isric.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!